# No memory leak, but confusing errors from valgrind when using malloc and file pointers

Tags: c, file-io, printf, malloc, valgrind

This reads from an already existing text file and creates 6 outfiles of little snippets from the infile. It works as predicted, but upon running valgrind I get multiple errors. However, there is no memory leak:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char buffer[5];
    FILE* infile = fopen("clams.txt", "r");
    if (infile == NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        fread(buffer, sizeof(char), 5, infile);

        char* filename = malloc(sizeof(char) * 4);                        //line 17
        sprintf(filename,"%03i.txt", i);
        printf("%c%c%c\n", filename[0], filename[1], filename[2]);        //19

        FILE* outfile = fopen(filename, "w");                             //21
        if (outfile == NULL)
        {
            return 2;
        }
        fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), 5, outfile);

        fclose(outfile);
        free(filename);
    }
    fclose(infile);
}
```

Valgrind said:

```
==1042== Invalid write of size 1
==1042==    at 0x4C762B4: _IO_default_xsputn (genops.c:394)
==1042==    by 0x4C762B4: _IO_default_xsputn (genops.c:370)
==1042==    by 0x4C5B165: __vfprintf_internal (vfprintf-internal.c:1719)
==1042==    by 0x4C69278: __vsprintf_internal (iovsprintf.c:95)
==1042==    by 0x4C46047: sprintf (sprintf.c:30)
==1042==    by 0x401234: main (filename.c:18)
==1042==  Address 0x4dd62a4 is 0 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd
==1042==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==1042==    by 0x401218: main (filename.c:17)
==1042== 
==1042== Invalid write of size 1
==1042==    at 0x4C6927E: __vsprintf_internal (iovsprintf.c:97)
==1042==    by 0x4C46047: sprintf (sprintf.c:30)
==1042==    by 0x401234: main (filename.c:18)
==1042==  Address 0x4dd62a7 is 3 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd
==1042==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==1042==    by 0x401218: main (filename.c:17)
==1042== 
000
==1042== Syscall param openat(filename) points to unaddressable byte(s)
==1042==    at 0x4CF1EAB: open (open64.c:48)
==1042==    by 0x4C74195: _IO_file_open (fileops.c:189)
==1042==    by 0x4C74459: _IO_file_fopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:281)
==1042==    by 0x4C66B0D: __fopen_internal (iofopen.c:75)
==1042==    by 0x4C66B0D: fopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofopen.c:86)
==1042==    by 0x401275: main (filename.c:21)
==1042==  Address 0x4dd62a4 is 0 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd
==1042==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==1042==    by 0x401218: main (filename.c:17)
==1042== 
001
002
003
004
005
==1042== 
==1042== HEAP SUMMARY:
==1042==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1042==   total heap usage: 20 allocs, 20 frees, 32,000 bytes allocated
==1042== 
==1042== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==1042== 
==1042== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==1042== ERROR SUMMARY: 30 errors from 3 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

(`filename.c` is the name of my program)

The only way I've been able to eliminate the errors is by changing line 17 to allocate 8 or more bytes. Anything between 4 and 7 inclusive gives me errors. I am confused as to why this is, given each string of 3 chars  and the `\0` should only take 4 bytes to store.

If I kept `malloc(4)`, should I be concerned about those errors? For a similar program that uses much more memory (e.g. images instead of text), can those errors eventually lead to a crash or segmentation fault?

Comment: `char* filename = malloc(sizeof(char) * 4);` allocates 4-bytes. `sprintf(filename,"%03i.txt", i);` attempts to store 8-bytes (Uh oh....)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is clear by looking at the following two lines:

```c
char* filename = malloc(sizeof(char) * 4); // 17
sprintf(filename, "%03i.txt", i);          // 18
```

At line 17 you allocate 4 bytes, which is enough space for a string of 3 characters plus a terminator (`\0`). Then, right after that, you *write* into that string more than 3 characters: at least 4 just from `.txt`, and then some more due to the `%03i`.

You should instead allocate more space. A conservative estimate for the needed size of the string holding the file name would be 4 (`.txt`) + 3 (since `i` can assume values from `0` to `5` and is padded to 3 decimal digits) + 1 (`\0` terminator), so a total of 8 bytes.

This is why changing that `malloc(4)` into a `malloc(8)` does not produce errors.

By the way, for such a small buffer, you can avoid complicating things with `malloc`/`free` and just declare it on the stack as a local variable:

```c
char filename[8];
```

> If I kept `malloc(4)`, should I be concerned about those errors?

Yes, you're writing past the end of an allocated buffer, which is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in C, which means your program can easily crash, segfault, or do worse things.

> For a similar program that uses much more memory (e.g. images instead of text), can those errors eventually lead to a crash or segmentation fault?

Even for the small program you just provided those errors can result in a crash, so yes.